# simple SQL query to find average based on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

```
 GAME                                 TIME
 1                                    00:23:24
 2                                    00:19:38                
 3                                    00:09:23
 4
```

I am trying to write a query which gives the average amount of time people spend on each game (in minutes) and produce a list of top 10 games (in terms max average time spent)?

Bit stuck from here ;

```
'''select from table_name 

GAME,  AVG(TIME), 
GROUP_BY GAME 
LIMIT 10;'''
```

Comment: Is it Mysql or Sql Server

Comment: Are you using MySQL or other DBMS? Because the syntax may be different.

Comment: I am usin PostgreSQL

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like your `TIME` column is also of type `TIME`. In PostgreSQL, `TIME` is for the time of the day, not for duration. You might want to consider using `INTERVAL`, as it will allow you to go further than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `order by` and `limit`?

```
select GAME, AVG(TIME) as avg_time
from table_name
group by game
order by avg_time desc
limit 10
```

Comment: This works, but it also returns seconds, and I want to not show seconds, how would I break up the time components?

Comment: `extract(field from expr)` returns a [component](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) of the interval. `field` can be `hour`, `minute`, `second` etc.